# Folder in start menu/installation folder still exists,After uninstallation using NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

I have written nsis script for Java project.once i have clicked uninstaller.exe

```
Start menu >all programs >my application
```

all the files are removed successfully from location of installed.but the problem is, folder in STARTMENU/installation  folder still exists,after clicking uninstallation.I dont know why this happened? I have used windows 7.

```
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$(^Name)"
    Delete /REBOOTOK "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuGroup\Uninstall $(^Name).lnk"
    Delete /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe
```

I have used above code.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the code to remove the directory? `RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuGroup"`

It is also important to use `RequestExecutionLevel` so you don't run into [compatibility issues](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista)...

Comment: Thanks.RMDir /r "$SMPROGRAMS\$StartMenuGroup" then only working fine.Also needed RequestExectionlevel.what is use of this? I have set this value RequestExectionlevel admin.finally uninstalled  successfully.

Comment: It adds the "UAC bits" to the exe manifest and disables pre-Vista application compatibility hacks. And you don't need the /r if you are already deleting the shortcuts first...